# C4 Xcode projects never recognize ios devices

Tags: c4

I'm finding that C4 projects, and only C4 projects, do not recognise connected iOS devices.

The run menu only shows "iOS Device".

This isn't a problem with any of my other Xcode projects.

I'm using a iphone4s running ios 5.1.1, and i realize the base sdk is set to iOS 6. This is the case with other projects though and I'm not encountering this issue there.

---

okay, the problem was that i had project build setting 'deployment target' = 6.0 for a 5.1.1 device.. i only knew about 'base sdk' until now :)

Comment: I haven't upgraded to iOS 6 on my home computer, yet. But, just to make sure... You say that other projects are allowing you to compile iOS6 SDK projects to an iOS5 device? I will be able to work out the issue when I get back to my machine at work.

Comment: yes, my other projects also target iOS 6.0 and i can run these on the same iOS 5.1.1 device

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it, something I haven't run into before. I'll give you an answer probably tomorrow, monday latest. Hopefully the simulator will be okay for now.

Comment: Just had a thought. What is the deployment target for the C4 project? Click on the project at the top of the navigator, and then Build Settings, then search for "deployment target"... If it's 6.0 (or latest) then maybe you can change it to 5.1 and see if that works.

Comment: aaah, the deployment target was 6.0 - switching it to 5.1 fixed this issue! sorry, i only had the "base sdk" project attribute in mind. thanks a lot!

Comment: Just add an answer yourself and accept it. Will make the question closed.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with the deployment target of the project.

I believe that the current installer doesn't account for a specific iOS target, but creates with a "latest" deployment target option. So, for iOS6 environments this will need to be changed in order to build for iOS5 devices.

You can do this by following these steps:

1. Click on the project at the top of the navigator pane (on the left-side of the Xcode window)
2. Click on the Build Settings tab which appears in the main content area.
3. In the Build Settings area, search for the term "deployment target"
4. Change the target option to the same as your device